# can't btrfs send from a read-only filesystem

Tags: btrfs

So, I corrupted my btrfs root filesystem a little. Now when I boot, mounting root read-write fails and the filesystem gets mounted read-only instead. Every file I try to read seems normal, so I assume the corruption is fairly limited.

I have a bunch of local snapshots. My hope is that the corruption doesn't affect them all; I'd like to copy as many of them as I can to my external backup disk before doing anything more drastic to try to fix things. But `btrfs send` fails with `-30 (Read-only file system)`.

- Does `btrfs send` really never work if the *sending* filesystem is mounted read-only? That would surprise me since it doesn't seem like it needs to write anything there.
- If so, is this because `btrfs send` actually does write to the sending filesystem, or is there some other reason why it does this check?
- Any workarounds? Currently I'm planning to just rsync the snapshots, but of course that's much slower.

(I will upvote answers that only address one of the above bullet points, if addressing the others seems too difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this on my `ztest` VM (which I use for testing/practising zfs, btrfs, mdadm, lvm and similar stuff - the VM has 15 x 100MB virtual drives attached to it, from /dev/vda to /dev/vdo. They don't need to be large for the kind of tests I run on them).

Anyway, I was able to send a subvolume from a read-only btrfs mount to a file on another fs (/tank1, which is ZFS).  e.g.

```
# df -Th /b1
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vdb1      btrfs  190M  7.3M  148M   5% /b1

# btrfs filesystem show /b1
Label: none  uuid: a5217930-73a9-4481-a14a-2c1974b3f2db
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 4.00MiB
    devid    1 size 190.00MiB used 104.00MiB path /dev/vdb1
    devid    2 size 190.00MiB used 104.00MiB path /dev/vdc1

# mount -o ro,remount /b1

# mount | grep /b1
/dev/vdb1 on /b1 type btrfs (ro,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)

# btrfs send /b1/sv1_20160506 -f /tank1/b1.send
At subvol /b1/sv1_20160506

# ls -l /tank1/b1.send 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2177404 Jun  7 01:24 /tank1/b1.send
```

I can think of two possibilities why it's not working on your system (but there may be others, and neither of these is necessarily correct):

1. btrfs may need to write to write to `/tmp` and `/tmp` is a subdir or `/` - I don't think this is very likely, but it might be worth trying to mount a tmpfs ramdisk over `/tmp`.
2. btrfs is behaving weirdly because your btrfs `/` fs is corrupted.

A possible workaround for either possibility might be to boot from a rescue CD/DVD/USB/etc **that has btrfs support** ([gparted](https://gparted.org/) and [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) are good choices) and try to `btrfs send` the snapshots from there (after manually mounting your exernal backup disk as RW).

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful :) In between posting my question and you posting your answer, I did finally manage to get a working bootable USB, and I saw the same behaviour there, except I think the thing that mattered was whether the drive had been forced read-only at the *start* of the send (in particular, it would force itself read-only *during* a send and that wouldn't interrupt it). My best guess now is that btrfs send uses this error code to mean "filesystem is in an error state that makes it read-only". I'll do some more investigation and accept your answer if nothing else comes up.